# Mean Red Value in an Image

Tags: java, image, image-processing

It is my understanding that this method would get the average brightness value of each red pixel in an image. Would this be correct? Does java's colour class have the capacity to do that or will this just return the average number of red pixels in an image?

```
    /*Mean Red*/
    public static double meanValueRed(BufferedImage image) {
    double sum = 0.0;

       for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); ++y){
         for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); ++x){
             Color r = new Color(image.getRGB(x, y));
             sum += r.getRed();
         }
       }
       return sum / (image.getWidth() * image.getHeight());
     }
```

Comment: @luk2302 as long as you talk about a single channel brightness is the same as value intensity or whatever so his approach is perfectly fine. although I'm sure that there are faster ways because this function involves a lot of function calls. I'm sure there is some way to work on the data directly. summing up every third byte would be much better than calling Color constructor for every pixel.

Comment: @Piglet ah, I over-read the "red" in "the average brightness value of each red pixel" :/ I take everything back!

Comment: So, my code is getting the average brightness value of each red pixel? @Piglet

Comment: no you don't get the average of each pixel, you get the average of all pixels.

Comment: Sorry, that was poorly worded on my part. I meant the average of all pixels. Thank you :) @Piglet